# JSON.Parse on Node.JS will not work everytime

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, syntax-error

Here is my code :

```
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(d);

    >> REDIS ACTION <<
    }
  });
});
req.end();
```

I assume that the JSON may be, and is most of the time large, but i don't understand this error :

```
    >> JSON DATA TRUNCATED, AND THIS DON'T HAVE TO BE DISPLAYED <<

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (A:\p
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:1
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readabl
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_s
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_co
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_cli
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

Can you explain me where is my fault and how to handle it ?

Comment: What type of request are you performing.  Could it be that the data coming back is not found ?   Or a bad status code?

Comment: I bet your request is pretty large. What I assume is that it's trying to parse a JSON string that isn't finished, e.g. it's trying to parse `"{'stuff': 'this is"` before you receive `"not finished'}"`

Comment: It's a GET request on a REST API application, that i don't own. And the status code is 200 when the errors occurs (it will not occur everytime).

Comment: Is it a single object, an array of objects? How large is the data? There are a couple ways to deal with it, depending on the size

Comment: ahh, so it's an asynchronous issues ! Ok, so how can i fix this, with this function ?
It's an array of object, everytime i request it, the object will have aproximatively the same size.

Comment: It's not an async issue, but an issue with chunking. Each "data" event isn't the entire object. You need to compose them before parsing. The problem is if it's a huge response, you could run out of memory.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to deal with ?

Comment: woops sorry, it's late, i've now understand what you've mean.

Answer (score 0):

As cdbajorin said, i needed to compose my data, because this occurs when node try to execute a command, but all the request isnt't already received.

Here is the code who solved my issue:

```
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  var response = '';

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    response += d;
  })

  res.on('end', () => {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);

    //EVERYTHING ELSE
      });
    }
  });
});
req.end();
```